# Guessing letter without having to capitalize input

Tags: java

I am new to this and I am having hard time with this code. I made a hangman game but I am having issues with the words that have a capital letter. If I don't input a capital letter the letter will not appear.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hangman {

    static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    static boolean isCorrect;

    private static Scanner input;

    private static Scanner input2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File filename = new File("hangman.txt");
        if (!filename.exists()) {
            System.out.println(filename.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(filename + " does not exist.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            input2 = new Scanner(filename);
            while (input2.hasNext()) {
                words.add(input2.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        input2.close();

        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playStarts = "y";
        int wins = 0;
        int loses = 0;
        final int MAX_GUESSES = 11;
        List<String> usedWords = new ArrayList<>();
        while (playStarts.equals("y")) {
            String word = getWord();
            usedWords.add(word);
            String secretWord = getSecretWord(word);
            int missCount = 0;
            while (!word.equals(secretWord)) {

                System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + secretWord + " > ");
                char ch = input.next().charAt(0);

                if (!isAlreadyInWord(secretWord, ch)) {

                    secretWord = getGuess(word, secretWord, ch);

                    if (!isCorrect) {
                        System.out.print(ch + " is not in the word.");
                        missCount++;
                        System.out.println(" You missed "+ missCount + " times");
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println(ch + " is already in word.");
                }
                if (missCount == MAX_GUESSES) {
                    System.out.println("You reached max number of guesses.");break;
                }
            }
            if (missCount == MAX_GUESSES) {
                loses++;
            } else {
                wins++;
            }
            System.out.println("The word is " + word + ". You missed " + missCount + " times");
            System.out.println("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n >");
            playStarts = input.next();

        }
        System.out.println("Number of wins is " + wins + ".");
        System.out.println("Number of loses is " + loses + ".");
        System.out.println("Used words:");
        for (String word : usedWords) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public static String getWord() {
        return words.get((int) (Math.random() * words.size()));
    }

    public static String getSecretWord(String word) {

        String hidden = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            hidden += "*";
        }
        return hidden;
    }

    static public String getGuess(String word, String secretWord, char ch) {

        isCorrect = false;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(secretWord);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

            //I think the issue is in this section of the code:

            if (ch == word.charAt(i) && s.charAt(i) == '*') {
                isCorrect = true;
                s = s.deleteCharAt(i);
                s = s.insert(i, ch);
            }
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    public static boolean isAlreadyInWord(String secretWord, char ch) {

        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {

            if (ch == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code works fine but I just have an issue with the capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

If your speculation be correct, the comparing the lowercase of both sides of the equation should fix the problem:

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(ch) == Character.toLowerCase(secretWord.charAt(i)) {
    return true;
}
```

Better yet, you can lowercase the user character input when it actually happens:

```
System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + secretWord + " > ");
char ch = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
```

Comment: I tried the second part it didn't work, do i need to use both parts of the solution?

Comment: @George The second part is only part of what you would have to do.  I am simply saying that as you take inputs for the word to guess and the letter to guess, lowercase them right away, so that later on when you compare them, you can be certain both cases would be the same.

Comment: You didn't post your full code, hence I didn't post a full solution.

Comment: My answer isn't going to change.  You need to be in control of your code at all times.  Just keep everything lowercase and then you don't need to worry it when doing comparisons.

Comment: the words are chosen randomly and some of them have capital letters in them. its not something i can control

Comment: Yes it is.  Just call `toLowerCase` on the string, or use `Character.toLowerCase` if it is a single character.

Answer (score 0):

There are some handy functions in the Character class that you can use (Character.toUpperCase() and toLowerCase()) that can help you compare whether the characters match.

`if (Character.toLowerCase(ch) == Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) && s.charAt(i) == '*')` will always be checking two lowercase letters, so the case of neither `ch` or `word.charAt(i)` will matter.